# PL/SQL Trigger doesn't work on brand new inserted data

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

I've created a trigger to check if someone updated a salary or inserted a new employee on the employees table using the procedure for checking, below is my code for my procedure and my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_salary (pjobid employees.job_id%type, psal employees.salary%type)
IS

BEGIN
    
    FOR i in (SELECT min_salary, max_salary
                FROM jobs
                WHERE job_id = pjobid)
    LOOP
        IF psal < i.min_salary OR psal > i.max_salary THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Invalid salary ' || psal || '. Salaries for job ' || pjobid || ' must be between ' || i.min_salary || ' and ' || i.max_salary);
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Salary is okay!');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

END check_salary;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_salary_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.salary != old.salary OR new.job_id != old.job_id)
BEGIN
    check_salary(:old.job_id, :new.salary);
END check_salary_trg;
```

Now it works normally when i try to update the salary of the specific employee that is already declared on the table (result is the one that is commented):

```
UPDATE employees
    SET salary = 2800
WHERE employee_id = 115;
--ORA-20001: Invalid salary 2800. Salaries for job HR_REP must be between 4000 and 9000
```

But, I'm wondering why it won't work when i have manually inserted the data when the insert was already declared on the trigger

```
INSERT INTO employees(first_name, last_name, email, department_id, job_id, hire_date) VALUES ('Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'loremipsum', 30, 'SAL_REP', TRUNC(sysdate));
```

OR when i use my add_employee procedure that is inside on my package, below is the code:

```
PROCEDURE ADD_EMPLOYEE(vfirstname        employees.first_name%type,
                     vlastname       employees.last_name%type,
                     vdepid      employees.department_id%type,
                     vjob        employees.job_id%type := 'SA_REP')
    IS
        vemail  employees.email%type;
    BEGIN
        vemail := upper(substr(vfirstname, 1, 1)) || upper(substr(vlastname,1,7));
        IF valid_deptid(vdepid) THEN
            INSERT INTO employees(first_name, last_name, email, department_id, job_id, employee_id, hire_date)
            VALUES(vfirstname, vlastname, vemail, vdepid, vjob, employees_seq.nextval, TRUNC(SYSDATE));
            COMMIT;
        ELSE
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, 'Invalid Department ID');
        END IF;
    END ADD_EMPLOYEE;

PROCEDURE ADD_EMPLOYEE(vfirstname       employees.first_name%type,
                     vlast_name      employees.last_name%type,
                     vemail      employees.email%type,
                     vjob        employees.job_id%type := 'SA_REP',
                     vmgr        employees.manager_id%type := 145,
                     vsalary         employees.salary%type := 1000,
                     vcomm       employees.commission_pct%type := 0,
                     vdepid      employees.department_id%type := 30)
    IS
    BEGIN
        IF valid_deptid(vdepid) THEN
            INSERT INTO employees(first_name, last_name, email, department_id, job_id, manager_id, salary, commission_pct, employee_id, hire_date)
            VALUES(vfirstname, vlast_name, vemail, vdepid, vjob, vmgr, vsalary, vcomm, employees_seq.nextval, TRUNC(SYSDATE));
            COMMIT;
        ELSE
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, 'Invalid Department ID');
        END IF;
    END ADD_EMPLOYEE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@KoenLostrie is absolutely correct as to *Why your trigger does not fire on Insert*. But that is just half the problem. But, the other issue stems from the same misconception: NULL values The call to `check_salary` passes `:old.job_id` but it is still null, resulting in cursor ( `for i in (Select ...)`) returning no rows  when it attempts 'WHERE job_id = null`. However there is no exception then a cursor returns no rows, the loop is simply not entered. You need to pass ':new.job_id'. You would also want the new job id on Update as well. Image an employee gets a promotion the update is like to be something like:

```
update employee 
   set job_id = 1011 
     , salary = 50000.00 
 where employee = 115;
```

Finally, processing a cursor is at dangerous at best. Doing so at lease implies you allow multiple rows in the `Jobs` for a given job_id. What happens when those rows have different `min_salary` and `max_salary` You can update the procedure or just do everything in the trigger and eliminate the procedure.

```
create or replace trigger check_salary_trg
   before insert or update on employees
      for each row
declare
    e_invalid_salary_range; 
    l_job  jobs%rowtype; 
begin
    select *
      from jobs
      into l_job
     where job_id = :new.job_id; 
     
     if :new.salary < l_job.min_salary 
     or :new.salary > l_job.max_salary
     then 
         raise  e_invalid_salary_range; ; 
     end if; 
 
exception 
    when e_invalid_salary_range then 
          raise_application_error(-20001, 'Invalid salary ' || psal || 
                                  '. Salaries for job ' || pjobid || 
                                  ' must be between ' ||  l_job.min_salary || 
                                  ' and ' ||  l_job.max_salary
                                  );
                           
end check_salary_trg;
```

You could add handling `no_data_found` and `too_many_rows` the the exception block, but those are better handled with constraints.

Comment: Thanks @Belayer, you're absolutely right. I looked at the trigger, noticed the problem and wrote my answer based on that observation without looking at the rest of the code.

Answer (score 3):

Congrats on the well documented question.

The issue is with the `WHEN` clause of the trigger. On insert the old value is `NULL` and in oracle, you can't compare to NULL using "=" or "!=".

Check this example:

```
PDB1--KOEN>create table trigger_test 
  2  (name VARCHAR2(10));

Table TRIGGER_TEST created.

PDB1--KOEN>CREATE OR REPLACE trigger trigger_test_t1
  2  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON trigger_test
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  WHEN (new.name != old.name) 
  5  BEGIN
  6    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Some error !');
  7  END trigger_test_t1;
  8  /

Trigger TRIGGER_TEST_T1 compiled

PDB1--KOEN>INSERT INTO trigger_test (name) values ('koen');

1 row inserted.

PDB1--KOEN>UPDATE trigger_test set name = 'steven';

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
UPDATE trigger_test set name = 'steven'
Error report -
ORA-20001: Some error !
ORA-06512: at "KOEN.TRIGGER_TEST_T1", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'KOEN.TRIGGER_TEST_T1'
```

That is exactly the behaviour you're seeing in your code. On insert the trigger doesn't seem to fire. Well... it doesn't because in oracle, `'x' != NULL`  yields false. See info at the bottom of this answer. Here is the proof. Let's recreate the trigger with an `NVL` function wrapped around the old value.

```
PDB1--KOEN>CREATE OR REPLACE trigger trigger_test_t1
  2  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON trigger_test
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  WHEN (new.name != NVL(old.name,'x'))
  5  -- above is similar to this
  6  --WHEN (new.name <> old.name or
  7  --     (new.name is null and old.name is not NULL) or
  8  --     (new.name is not null and old.name is NULL) )
  9  BEGIN
 10    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Some error !');
 11  END trigger_test_t1;
 12  /

Trigger TRIGGER_TEST_T1 compiled


PDB1--KOEN>INSERT INTO trigger_test (name) values ('jennifer');

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
INSERT INTO trigger_test (name) values ('jennifer')
Error report -
ORA-20001: Some error !
ORA-06512: at "KOEN.TRIGGER_TEST_T1", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'KOEN.TRIGGER_TEST_T1'
```

There you go. It now fires on insert.

Now why is this happening ? According to the docs:
*Because null represents a lack of data, a null cannot be equal or unequal to any value or to another null. However, Oracle considers two nulls to be equal when evaluating a DECODE function.* Check the docs or read up on it in this *20 year old* answer on [asktom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1274000564279)

Comment: Hi, I really like your explanation and i really understood it. But the problem still persist and still works whenever i'm inserting a data to the table, it just won't activate the trigger..

Comment: In addition to this, I've tried using your example and it works! But when I applied it to my code it won't work and it just ignores the trigger..

Comment: Check the very complete answer by @Belayer, the trigger is not the only issue as he describes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the wonderful answers! I've learned a lot thanks to them.

Upon inspecting my code especially my trigger, I made a mistake on passing the `:old.job_id` to my `check_salary` procedure instead of the `:new.job_id`, that's why i keep wondering why my INSERT is working even if the salary that is being passed is below the `min_salary` and `max_salary` of the job.
So this now my code:

check_salary procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_salary (pjobid employees.job_id%type, psal employees.salary%type)
IS

BEGIN
    
    FOR i in (SELECT min_salary, max_salary
                FROM jobs
                WHERE job_id = pjobid)
    LOOP
        IF psal < i.min_salary OR psal > i.max_salary THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Invalid salary ' || psal || '. Salaries for job ' || pjobid || ' must be between ' || i.min_salary || ' and ' || i.max_salary);
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Salary is okay!');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

END check_salary;
/
```

check_salary_trg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_salary_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.salary != NVL(old.salary, 0) OR new.job_id != NVL(old.job_id, 'x'))
BEGIN
    check_salary(:new.job_id, :new.salary);
END check_salary_trg;
/
```

and the results whenever i'm passing data thru insert and update

```
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id, first_name, last_name, email, department_id, job_id, hire_date, salary) 
                VALUES (employees_seq.nextval, 'Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'loremipsum', 30, 'SA_REP', TRUNC(sysdate), 5000);
```

**`ORA-20001: Invalid salary 5000. Salaries for job SA_REP must be between 6000 and 12008`**

```
UPDATE employees
    SET job_id = 'ST_MAN'
WHERE last_name = 'Beh'
```

**`ORA-20001: Invalid salary 9000. Salaries for job ST_MAN must be between 5500 and 8500`**

```
UPDATE employees
    SET salary = 2800
WHERE employee_id = 115;
--1 row(s) updated.
--Salary is okay!
-- will work since min_salary and max_salary of PU_CLERK is 2500 and 5500
```